# Old comic book, war with the moon, Pan-ku Chinese first man

Tags: story-identification, comics, space-exploration, moon

Back in the 1960s, I once read an old, second hand, comic book about relations between the Earth and the Moon.  In some television messages from the Moon, the hero saw a beautiful Moon woman, while other messages from the moon involved a yellow-skinned man with antlers on his head named Pan-ku.

Pan-ku was correctly identified in the comic with a mythical Chinese first man or creation god.  As a result some Chinese people turned to his side.

As the Moon began to attack the Earth, the hero traveled to the Moon in a rocket ship hoping to meet the beautiful Moon woman and - oh yes - maybe get around to saving the Earth from the devastating lunar attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be **Rocket to the Moon**, an adaptation of **Maza of the Moon** by Otis Adelbert Kline. I haven't read the comic version, but the plot you describe is an exact match to the novel. The Emperor of the Moon being named P'an-ku has got to be distinctive.

The novel was published in 1929 (magazine)/1930 (book). Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maza_of_the_Moon#Comic_adaptation) says the comic adaptation was published in 1951, so it would have been old already in the 1960s.

The antlers are probably a comic-specific embellishment. In the book version, the TV image of P'an-ku shows him with

> a tall pointed helmet of gleaming yellow metal, built up in tiers like
>   a pagoda and ending in a sharp spike. His body was encased in
>   scale-like armor of the same yellow metal

Comment: cometaryorbit - you're right.  I was planning to answer this myself if nobody answered within a reasonable time.  A few years ago I remembered this comic and investigated.  For some reason I thought of Maza of the Moon, which I never read, and found a synopsis.  Once I read about Pan-ku I knew the comic based on Maza was it.