# Comic book with Moon Base and Killer Robot

Tags: story-identification, comics

In this question:

[Blackhawk comic book, moon base, killer robot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178752/blackhawk-comic-book-moon-base-killer-robot)[1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178752/blackhawk-comic-book-moon-base-killer-robot)

I asked about a comic book story I read in the 1960s though it could have been published earlier.  As I remember, a group of Earthlings who didn't have space travel abilities somehow ended up in a base on the moon built by someone and were endangered by a killer robot.  As I remember, they set the killer robot on fire to destroy it.

I thought that it could be a Blackhawk comic.  But I haven't been able to find a Blackhawk story set in outer space that fits my memory.

This could have been a story in an anthology comic, but I think it was a story in a comic series.

So maybe it was a Tomahawk (1947-1972) comic book instead.  I head that some of the Tomahawk stories had science fictional elements.

Does anyone remember any Tomahawk stories in outer space or with killer robots?

Comment: Is this question asking about the same id?

Comment: FWIW if this is about the same story you should really edit the old question to include the new detail and potentially bounty the old one. If it is the same story this should be duple closed, I will hold off until you confirm though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blackhawk comic book, moon base, killer robot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178752/blackhawk-comic-book-moon-base-killer-robot)

Comment: Not a dup unless OP has confirmed both are the same story.