# Old comic book, space opera or planetary romance, nonhuman villain

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens, space-opera

I asked a question about an old science ficition comic book here:

[Old comic book, war with the moon, Pan-ku Chinese first man](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178586/old-comic-book-war-with-the-moon-pan-ku-chinese-first-man)[1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178586/old-comic-book-war-with-the-moon-pan-ku-chinese-first-man)

I already knew the answer, and planned to answer myself if nobody else answered, but the question was answered pretty quick.

Back in the 1960s I read another old science fiction comic book, possibly in the same batch of old comic books as the one asked about previously.

This comic book could have had an original story or been based on a novel like the one in my previous question.  The genre would seem to be space opera or planetary romance as far as I can remember.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_opera[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_opera)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_romance[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_romance)

I mainly remember a caravan crossing the desert on Earth or some other planet and being attacked by a band of outlaws.  The outlaw leader was obviously nonhuman and may have been called "the Gargoyle".  The most nonhuman part of his anatomy was several tendrils that extended from his chin into his chest.  That is what I remember most from the comic.

I suppose that he could have worn a spacesuit and had tubes going from his spacesuit into his helmet, but I remember him being bareheaded and those being parts of his body.

This time I don't remember anything about the comic book except what I wrote and hope that someone can identify it.